# Executing function at end of html5 video

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I have a html video, and I am wanting to run a function when a video ends. I have tried the following but I get nothing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('video').live('ended',function(){

        alert('video ended');

    });

});
```

Any ideas why this isn't triggering at the end of a video? Or have I not provided enough information to answer anything here?

Note: I'm using live() function and not on() because of the need for jQuery 1.7 with this project.

Comment: .on was added in jquery version 1.7. .live was deprecated in 1.7

Comment: @ryadavilli yes but to my knowledge live() still functions in 1.7 doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it should, it was deprecated and not removed till 1.9. My comment was to suggest that you could still use .on. as it was added in 1.7 itself.

Comment: Thank you for that! Having a dumb moment here.

Answer (score 73):

For your paste & copy pleasure the jQuery solution:

```html
<video width="320" height="240">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>/*<![CDATA[*/
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('video').on('ended',function(){
      console.log('Video has ended!');
    });
  });
/*]]>*/</script>
```

Replace the `'video'`-part with the correct selector for your video.

**EDIT**: Here is the solution without jQuery:

```html
<video width="320" height="240">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<script>/*<![CDATA[*/
  document.querySelector('video').addEventListener('ended',function(){
    console.log('Video has ended!');
  }, false);
/*]]>*/</script>
```

Replace the `'video'`-part with the correct selector for your video.

Answer (score 14):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script>
function videoEnded() {
    alert('video ended');
}


    </script>
</head>
<body>

<video src="video/endscene.mp4" id="video" controls onended="videoEnded()">
    video not supported
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

use **onended** event

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

video.onended = function(e) {
  alert('video ended');
}
```

Read more on [**Everything you need to know about HTML5 video and audio**](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/)

Comment: That looks great. Something I failed to mention is the video is loaded  into the dom after the page is loaded, hence why I am using live('ended'). I'm not sure if then I can use your function as is due to this.

Answer (score 5):

Here is something you can try:

```
$(document).on('ended', 'video', function (e) {
    alert('video ended');
});
```

You said that the video is dynamically inserted *after* the DOM is loaded. In this script, you search on DOM for the `video` element and binds it with the `ended` function.

Here is the documentation for [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
Here is the SO question for [dynamic items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

the only way i managed it to work is the following code:

```
$('video')[0].on('ended',function(){
    console.log('Video has ended!');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use on in the place of live. Because on method is supported by jquery new versions and live is deprecated in new versions.

You can replace your code to this and your problem will be solved.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('video').on('ended',function(){

    alert('video ended');

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script>
  function videoEnded() {
      location.href="https://www.google.com";
   }
</script>

<video id="myVideo" width="640" height="480" controls autoplay onended="videoEnded()">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```